# How to prevent users from changing Workbench Access Section

Tags: 7, workbench

I have different authors set up with rights to edit different pages of my site (using Workbench Access), and an unfortunate side effect of this is that, when editing a page, they can also assign it to a different Workbench Access Section.

This would, for instance, allow them to accidentally lock themselves out of a page, or allow someone else to gain editing rights to it.  This is definitely not a good thing.

I don't see anything in the permissions that would allow me to fix this, but here are my settings in case some are somehow relevant, despite appearing otherwise.[image]

How can I fix this?  How can I prevent access to this field?

Answer (score 1):

Users can only assign a node to a workbench access section if their user or role has permissions to do so? But perhaps it gets tricky with assigning permissions to the different transitions too.

Anyway, you can lock the workbench access field on node edits, so they can't lock themselves out if you like:

```
<?php
function MODULENAME_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Make sure this node type actually has workflow_access stuff setup.
  if (isset($form_state['node']->type) && variable_get('workbench_access_node_type_' . $form_state['node']->type, 1) == 0) {
    return;
  }
  // Once the page has been created, don't allow changing the workbench area again.
  if (preg_match("/^node\/([0-9]+)\/edit/", current_path())) {
    $form['workbench_access']['#disabled'] = TRUE; 
  }
}
```